# Covered vent under carpet

Tags: vent, carpet

I got carpet installed from Lowe's. The installers have covered the ac vents and return air vents in some areas. I have called them to fix it but I am not sure how can they do it and if they will find all the vents.

1. I want to find out myself where all the vents are?
2. And if they miss again or don't do it at all, how to do it myself?

Comment: If the vents are metallic, you may be able to find them with a strong magnet?

Comment: The more I read about the mistakes made by big-box installers, the less desire I have to ever have one come near my home. :( I'll buy my carpet at the carpet store and have their installers handle it. Not a ding on the OP, just a lesson I'm learning from all the questions here.

Comment: First thing: stop all payments to Lowe's until the job is done right.

Comment: They take full payment in advance for the job. Its so hard to find anyone to do anything.. We did not expect much but thought Lowe's would do a better job than this.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason if you get on your hands and knees that you cannot feel the grates or empty space.    I would check all walls from 8-16" and press down with my hand.   But even if you find them, what will you do?

Also an easier way is to have Lowe's get their stupid installer out and lift up the carpet on all walls to make sure there are no vents under.   There are a lot of things on flooring installs that are part of the home owners to-dos...   The vents are 100% on the installer.

Comment: I got on my hands and knees and found a couple of them.. but I could not find any in one of the bedrooms. I know there is at least one in there. I hoped I could feel the hot or cold air of the feel the grates.. but no.. it feels like wood everywhere.

Comment: This is absolutely on them.  Suggest you insist they pull the carpet edge up all around every room to ensure it is done correctly.

Comment: @ok1more - you cannot just cut this out.   First without the right tools it will be hard.   Second it will look sloppy without it be cut/secured right.   Third if you cut it out and something happens you may void any warranty you have.    Carpet installers cut these out every day.  I have seen guys thrown down carpet in a 2000 sq ft house and make 20 vent holes and this take them 3 hours.   You got some serious bozos.

Comment: I called Lowe's and they sent the guy out and he fixed it. He was confident that he has very good memory and he never forgets anything.. and then he realized he had forgotten a whole roll of padding at my house